# Rails Server runs form successfully only one after save and reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have 2 pieces of code that will only run once when I make a change and save the code in the form and then reload the form. The next time I open and run the form it fails to run. Every other part of my application runs just fine.

**The first is a datepicker:**

The datepicker only shows up the first time.

*Here is the coffee script:*

```
$.fn.extend {
  integrateDatepicker: (selector)->
    selector = selector || '.datepicker'
    $(@).find(selector).datepicker({"format": "dd/mm/yyyy"}) 
}
$(document).ready () ->
  $('body').integrateDatepicker()
```

*Here is the form snippet:*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= simple_form_for([@council_report]) do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.input :report_title %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.input :report_desc %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.input :report_date, as: :string, input_html: {class: 'datepicker'} %>
      </p>       
      <p>
        <%= f.submit  class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The second is a form post:**

The "create" action runs successfully only the first time the form loads.

*Here is the form snippet:*

```
<%= form_for(:select_asset, url: {action: "create"}) do |form| %>
  <% @assets_not_in.each_with_index do |asset_not_in, index|
       asset = Asset.find(asset_not_in.id) %>
       <%= fields_for "assets_to_check[#{index}]", asset_not_in do |f| %>
         <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => asset.id %>
         <tr>
           <td><%= asset.asset_name %></td>
           <td><%= asset_type_desc(asset.asset_type_code) %></td>
           <td><%= asset.address.address_long %></td>
           <td><%= asset.address.postcode %></td>
           <td><%= asset.address.state_code %></td>
           <td><%= f.check_box :add_asset %></td>
         </tr>
       <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>

  <%= link_to 'Back', council_report_report_assets_path(@council_report) %>
  <%= form.submit "Add Assets", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone out there experienced this behaviour?
2. What is wrong with my application causing this bizaire behaviour?
3. Of course, how do I fix it?

Comment: are you using turbolinks? that could cause issues with the datepicked. the jquery-turbolinks gem is the fix if that is the issue

Comment: I do have the turbolinks gem installed. How do I know if I am using them?

Comment: Sorted it. Thanks. I have turned turbolinks off no for every form body, now how do I only turn it off for specific forms if they all inherit the same application layout?

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks is enabled by default in rails 4 and will cause issues with jQuery's `$(document).ready`.

To verify you're runnign turbolinks, check your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Look for the lines

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

in the `head`. If they are set to true, try adding the `jquery-turbolinks` gem to your Gemfile.

Turbolinks renders some parts of the page via ajax, so `$(document).ready` will not fire unless you enter the site through that page OR do a hard refresh. The gem fixes this by automatically changing your `$(document).ready` listeners: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks

Comment: Turbolinks was causing the problem in both instances. I am still loading them but have turned them off in my layout/application.html.erb as follows: `<body data-no-turbolink>` Reading about turbolinks, I don't see the point if it won't render content like this ...

Comment: Try turning it back on and rebundling with the `jquery-turbolinks` gem, it should let your code work without any configurations. Turbolinks is love-it or hate-it, personally I like it because I think it improves the user experience and makes the app a little faster. It's worth experimenting with imo